# Проблемы с сокетами в java

Tags: сокеты, java

При попытке отправить сообщение получаю кучу ошибок. Вот Client:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

class SocketClient extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{

    JLabel text, clicked;
    JButton button;
    JPanel panel;
    JTextField textField;
    Socket socket = null;
    PrintWriter out = null;
    BufferedReader in = null;

    SocketClient()
    {   //Начало конструктора
        text = new JLabel("Текст для отправки через сокет:");
        textField = new JTextField(20);
        button = new JButton("Отправить");
        button.addActionListener(this);

        panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        panel.setBackground(Color.white);
        getContentPane().add(panel);
        panel.add("North", text);
        panel.add("Center", textField);
        panel.add("South", button);
    } //Конец конструктора

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
    {
        Object source = event.getSource();

        if(source == button)
        {
            //Передача данных через сокет
            String text = textField.getText();
            System.out.println(text);
            textField.setText(new String(""));

            //Получить текст с сервера
            try
            {
                String line = in.readLine();
                System.out.println("Text received :" + line);
            }

            catch (IOException e)
            {
                System.out.println("Read failed");
                System.exit(1);
            }
        }
    }

    public void listenSocket()
    {
        //Создать сокет
        try
        {
            socket = new Socket("localhost", 4444);
            out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
        }

        catch (UnknownHostException e)
        {
            System.out.println("Unknown host: localhost");
            System.exit(1);
        }

        catch  (IOException e)
        {
            System.out.println("Nowdced I/O");
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SocketClient frame = new SocketClient();
        frame.setTitle("Client");
        WindowListener l = new WindowAdapter()
        {
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e)
            {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        };

        frame.addWindowListener(l);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.listenSocket();
    }
}
```

**Добавлено.**

Ошибки:

`Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException at SocketClient.actionPerformed(SocketClient.java:50) at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source) at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source) at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source) at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source) at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source) at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source) at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source) at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source) at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source) at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source) at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source) at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source) at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source) at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source) at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source) at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source) at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source) at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source) at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(Unknown Source) at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source) at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source) at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source) at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source) at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source) at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source) at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source) at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source) at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source) at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source) at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source) at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)`

Comment: код твой? найти лучше рабочий пример в нэте и поюзай, что бы разобратся

Comment: Gorets, это сборная солянка. Я уже примеров 8 перелопатил, а результат один: “Не работает!!!!”

Comment: А что такое "не работает"? попробовал сам - код вполне себе работает. Может быть у Вас сервера нет? или не тот порт слушает...

Comment: может ты не знаешь как протестить все на одной машине под эклипсом? как переключить консоли?)

Comment: KoVadim, прога запускается, но она выдает ошибки вместо передачи сообщений ;)

Comment: я думаю в этом случае, не мешало бы выложить ошибки

Comment: Gorets, ого! Не знаю, это как?

Comment: ошибки:

Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at SocketClient.actionPerformed(SocketClient.java:50)
 at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
 at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
 at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
 at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
 at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)

Comment: at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)

Comment: at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
 at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)

Comment: at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)

Comment: at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)

Comment: Это всё шлак какой-то. Найдите нормальное сообщение об ошибке

Comment: А вы уверены, что подключение удалось? Если in = null (что следует из ваших ошибок), то вероятно открытие сокета зависло.. вероятно ждёт подключения. Возможно ошибка на серверной стороне.

Comment: class SocketClient extends JFrame implements ActionListener

Жесть! Из фрейма сделали кнопку и назвали ее SocketClient. О! Да тут еще и main есть...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На мой беглый взгляд по этому (*$"?%№;) коду ошибка кроется в конструкторе здесь:

```
button.addActionListener(this);
```

Объект пытается при создании себя использовать себя (еще не создавшегося).
Я вообще молчу о том, что непонятно чем является объект этого класса - Фреймом, Обработчиком событий или Протоколом работы сокета.

А вообще здесь собрано кода, который **можно и НУЖНО разбить как минимум на 3 класса**: GUI, Main и Protocol.

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка то обычное обращение к null pointer. Тем более ошибка в вашем коде

```
 SocketClient.actionPerformed(SocketClient.java:50) at
```

смотрите что у вас там на 50 строчке находится